# Could you help me understand this strange float issue?

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to learn html/css and now I am stuck trying to understand how `float` works.

I have the following issue: When the red div is aligned to right, the layout is how I intended to be. However, when I am aligning it to left the brown div goes to bottom.

Can someone explain why this happens?

I have an example set up at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/luisse/uX42F/)

```
<div id="container" style="width:300px;height="300px";float:right">
<div id="yellow" style="background-color:yellow;height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">yellow</div>
<div id="green" style="background-color:green;height:100px;width:100px;float:left;">green</div>
<div id="red" style="background-color:red;height:200px;width:100px;float:right;">red</div>
<div id="brown" style="background-color:brown;height:100px;width:100px;float:left;">brown</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good way to explain behaviour of brown div from your jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/luisse/uX42F/  (which is grey in my example for some unknown reason =) ) is to draw it :)

Draw 1 and 2

Imagine that last floated left element on the right side creates imagine line, you cannot place any left floated element below that line (well you can if you play with margins and positions but we are focusing on floats only).

Ok we are missing something between draw 2 and draw 3, if div 2 and 3 were same height div 4 would be sitting on the top of div 2 :)

(right floated divs are placed from right to left and last div on the left sets "imagine line"... its like this example watched in the mirror :P )

Draw 3

When div 3 is shorter than div 2, div 4 sits on top of it and now div 4 is the element which sets "our imagine" line where 5 div is placed now.

Draw 4

What happening we set float right on div 3?

Div 3 is not last floated left element, now line is set by div 2 that's why grey div sits on the top od div 2

Situation gets more complicated when we mix left and right floated divs, but it is good practice to play with it.

[image: float]

To avoid this sort of behaviour,it is good to create 3 columns first and place divs inside them, it will make your life easier especially if you have more "small boxes".

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
    <div class="box">9</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uX42F/5/

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

So I think what will help clear up any confusion is taking a look at what is actually happening here. When you set a group of elements to `float: left;` or `float: right;` you can think of it as putting them into two different groups. Each group stacks in order to the left or right, if one hits the edge of their containing `div` it will wrap down to the next line as normal.

In your first example with the red div was floated right, so it's in it's own group now and doesn't interact with the remaining floated left elements. That leaves the brown div to hit the container's edge, and wrap under the green element. If we expand the container you'll see it doesn't wrap and sits next to the green.

In the second example the red div is now part of the group. it's placed next to the green and then the brown wraps down below as in your example. Again if we expand the containing div it will sit next to the red block now.

**[EXAMPLE FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uX42F/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

From [CSS 2.1 section 9.5.1 Positioning the float: the 'float' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position):

> Here are the precise rules that govern the behavior of floats:
>
> 1. The left outer edge of a left-floating box may not be to the left of the left edge of its containing block. An analogous rule holds for right-floating elements.
> 2. If the current box is left-floating, and there are any left-floating boxes generated by elements earlier in the source document, then for each such earlier box, either the left outer edge of the current box must be to the right of the right outer edge of the earlier box, or its top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box. Analogous rules hold for right-floating boxes.
> 3. The right outer edge of a left-floating box may not be to the right of the left outer edge of any right-floating box that is next to it. Analogous rules hold for right-floating elements.
> 4. A floating box's outer top may not be higher than the top of its containing block. When the float occurs between two collapsing margins, the float is positioned as if it had an otherwise empty anonymous block parent taking part in the flow. The position of such a parent is defined by the rules in the section on margin collapsing.
> 5. The outer top of a floating box may not be higher than the outer top of any block or floated box generated by an element earlier in the source document.
> 6. The outer top of an element's floating box may not be higher than the top of any line-box containing a box generated by an element earlier in the source document.
> 7. A left-floating box that has another left-floating box to its left may not have its right outer edge to the right of its containing block's right edge. (Loosely: a left float may not stick out at the right edge, unless it is already as far to the left as possible. An analogous rule holds for right-floating elements.
> 8. A floating box must be placed as high as possible.
> 9. A left-floating box must be put as far to the left as possible, a right-floating box as far to the right as possible. A higher position is preferred over one that is further to the left/right.
>
> But in CSS 2.1, if, within the block formatting context, there is an in-flow negative vertical margin such that the float's position is above the position it would be at were all such negative margins set to zero, the position of the float is undefined.

Got that?

Actually, the behaviour you ask about can be explained by just rule 2. Taking the brown box as the "current box", if the red box is left aligned, then it participates in the "any left-floating boxes generated by elements earlier in the source document" and the brown box must be either to the right or below the red box. If the red box is right aligned, then it does not participate and the brown box can be placed higher.

Answer (score 1):

for one simple reason! you arrane your divs like this:
1- yellow
2- green
3- red
4- brown
so priority is the one that comes first. you put red before brown. so if you aligned red to right, the brown one finds some space to be aligned left! and it fills under the green one, because the red one is now aligned right with different prionrity. now you aligned red to left, your container has 300px and the brown one has not some space, so it drops after the red! because the red one has priority 3 and the brown one has not permission to fill the spaces before the red one. SO: the red one comes first and gain the 3rd 100px, and the brown one drops and fill the bottom spaces of container.
good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

We don't see your other divs, but when you use float the divs are intented to be put on a row. So float: right will put your div on the right and the next one is below.

Comment: Please use the jsfiddle link. It contains both situations. I solved that div displaying problem. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the link. It works fine, just how it's supposed to work. Putting left to the red div you don't allow more "left" space on the parent div, so the only place is below the yellow.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I really don't understand it. Maybe I am just dumb.

Comment: It's because of your content width:300px doesn't allow enough place for the child divs so the brown div is getting pushed down. Change it to 400px and the brown div will stay on the right http://jsfiddle.net/daguru/uX42F/2/

Comment: I did it. I wanted to understand why floating red to right or left affects the brown div. I wanted to understand very clear why.